# URL instead of file in linux command parameters

Tags: linux, command, url

Is there a way to put URL of a file instead of a file in parameters of a linux command?

To be specific I am looking for a way to store dhcp.lease file remotely but dhcp accept just file. How can I do someting like this:

```
dhcpd  -lf ftp://USER:PASS@IP_ADDR/PATH_TO_FILE
```

As I searched links does not work.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this - running a local daemon with a remote config file - by using something like sshfs, which mounts a remote directory securely:

```
sshfs USER@IP_ADDR:/path_to_file/ local_dir/
```

(To avoid a password prompt, use the public/private key system.)

But doing this would make the daemon less reliable, which is generally something to avoid. You may want to consider a synchronization mechanism instead.

Comment: this way just ssh is supported how about other protocols?

Comment: There are 3rd party products that can simulate a mount over FTP, but it's a bad idea. FTP is not secure and far less stable than ssh.

Answer (score 1):

To use the result of a command in bash you can use "$(command)" as placeholder.

In your case the command has to fetch a file with ftp and has to put it locally, then reference that local copy without interactive parts.

It is probably easier to write a full script in your use case.

Comment: This sounds nice, but how about the situation when dhcp wants to write to dhcp.lease file remotely?